# Get key (not index) from qualifying row in an associative array of associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, associative-array

Here my array:

```
$array = [
    'key1' => [
        'first' => 'azerty',
        'second' => 'qwerty'
    ],
    'key2' => [
        'first' => 'hello',
        'second' => 'world'
    ]
];
```

With the value 'qwerty' I would like to retrieve the 'key1'.

I looking for something like that:

```
$theKeyIWant = array_search('qwerty', array_column($array, 'second'));
```

But I get '0', instead of 'key1' (and I know that's how it works)

Anyone know how to adapt this code or know another code to get the key value?

Comment: Read the [top post](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) on the documentation for `array_search`: `array_column` does not preserve the keys for your array.

Comment: Yes, I know. So my question is: how to adapt this code to get the key value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight modification to your code to combine the keys and column values:

```
$theKeyIWant = array_search('qwerty', array_combine(array_keys($array), array_column($array, 'second')));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with seeking "something sexier" for this task is that if "sexier" means a "functional iterator", then that comes a cost of not being able to "return early" (doing unnecessary cycles).

If you want a single-line function to call, you can build your own and put it in a helpers file somewhere in your project.  My strong advice is to abandon "sexy" for this task and use a breakable foreach loop.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LPXHe))

```
function getRowKey($array, $column, $value) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
        if ($row[$column] === $value) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var_export(getRowKey($array, 'second', 'qwerty'));
```

---

If you are going to perform repeated searches on the same array and the second column is guaranteed to contain unique values, then you can convert the array into a lookup array without losing any data. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vSgRZ))

```
function restructure($array, $columnToKey) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
        $result[$row[$columnToKey]] = $row + ['oldKey' => $key];
    }
    return $result;
}

var_export(restructure($array, 'second')['qwerty']);
```

Comment: My array will not be too huge, so I'll take the sexier way. But thank you for your explanation. I keep this solution in mind and will use it next time if the situation allows.

Comment: Are the values in the `second` column guaranteed to be unique? If not, which first level key would you want if there where two qualifying rows in the array? The former or the latter?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this is to loop through the outer array and use **array_search()** to search for the value within each inner array.

```
$value = 'qwerty';
$theKeyIWant = null;

foreach ($array as $key => $innerArray) {
  if (array_search($value, $innerArray) !== false) {
    $theKeyIWant = $key;
    break;
  }
}

echo $theKeyIWant; // Output: key1
```

Comment: I'm looking for something sexier but yes this kind of code works

Answer (score 0):

`array_keys` returns an array of an array's keys.

```
<?php

$array = [
'key1' => [
    'first' => 'azerty',
    'second' => 'qwerty'
],
'key2' => [
    'first' => 'hello',
    'second' => 'world'
]
];
$theKeyIWant = array_search('qwerty', array_column($array, 'second'));
echo array_keys($array)[$theKeyIWant];
?>
```

[3V4l](https://3v4l.org/fYe7g)

Comment: I know PHP arrays are ordered, but that feels dirty. Then again, PHP _is_ dirty...